# Sessions Django: Daphne + Uwgsi

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, daphne

I am currently deploying a django project using channel 2.x with uwgsi for http requests and daphne for background tasks.

Daphne by itself is running correctly as well as uwgsi.

Configuration for both is the following:

```
location /stream {
    # daphne server running on port 8001 so we set a proxy to that url
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_redirect   off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}

# These requests are handled by uwsgi
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/project/socket;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Make the following two variables accessible to the application:
    uwsgi_param SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
    uwsgi_param SSL_CLIENT_RAW_CERT $ssl_client_raw_cert;
}
```

All background workers are preceded by **/stream**. All endpoints are protected. When login in and accessing endpoints such as **/api/v1/resource** it correctly returns the data but when triggering tasks via **/stream** I get permission denied (403). Debugging this behavior I have come to the conclusion that sessions are not persisted among Daphne and Uwsgi.

How can I achieve sessions to be shared between them?